# Twitter share with url adds space at start

Tags: url, twitter, share, social-networking, socialshare

I tried to share on twitter with following url.

https://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Then on the share textarea, I can see a space at start before the url. This is really annoying and I can't get rid of it. Anyone knows why there is space?

Answer (score 0):

If you share using the "text" parameter instead of "url" it doesn't add the space.

i.e.
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot - just saw the option to use "text" instead of "url" in their documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent)